# how to get the result of Inner join of two different classes in java 8

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, inner-join

Is there a way to carry out and get the result of  inner join between two different classes in java . 
For example I have :

class A

```
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private B b;
}
```

class B

```
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

I want to carry out a Inner join based on a single field `id`. Is it possible to have those result ? which way ? Thank you

Comment: What DBA library are you using?  Please add as a tag.

Comment: If b is a FK in the table, then select where b is not null

Answer (score 1):

@ManyToOne

@JoinColumn(name = "foreign_key" referencedColumnName = "primary/referenced key")

private B b;

Please refer to :
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/

Comment: Thank you for your help , I did add the annotation @Join , but how to get the result of that join ? there's a way to have the table that contains both class A and B ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is annotation in JPA

```
@JoinColumn(name = "nameOfColumn")
```

use it under

```
@ManyToOne
private B b;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , I did add the annotation @Join , but how to get the result of that join ? there's a way to have the table that contains both class A and B ? Thank you

Comment: Tables can't contain classes. They contain foreign keys on each other so that's why we use ORM frameworks. You just need to get some object and ORM such as Hibernate(JPA) will do everything.
Notice that JPA is specification and Hibernate is implementation.